# Member template functions returning a subtype

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, templates, visual-c++

Is there a correct way of defining a member function for a template class, that returns an instance of a subclass?

Here's an example that does not compile in VC++ 2010:

```
template<class T> class A {
public:
    class B {
    public:
        T i;
    };

    A();
    B* foo();
};

/////////////////////////////////////////////

template<class T> A<T>::A() {}

template<class T> A<T>::B* A<T>::foo() {
    cout << "foo" << endl;
    return new B();
}
```

I get

```
Error   8   error C1903: unable to recover from previous error(s); stopping compilation
```

at the line where the *definition* of `foo` starts.

I have the correct inclusions and namespace declarations for `iostream` etc.

Thanks guys!

**Edit:**

As requested, here's the complete list of errors, all at the same line:

```
Warning 1   warning C4346: 'A<T>::B' : dependent name is not a type
Error   2   error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '*'
Error   3   error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
Error   4   error C1903: unable to recover from previous error(s); stopping compilation
Warning 5   warning C4346: 'A<T>::B' : dependent name is not a type
Error   6   error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '*'
Error   7   error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
Error   8   error C1903: unable to recover from previous error(s); stopping compilation
```

Comment: Give us "previous error(s)" too. Maybe typename before A<T>::B is missing?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where and why do I have to put the "template" and "typename" keywords?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Name `A<T>::B` is depedent , you need to hint the compiler that depedented name is type

`template<class T> typename A<T>::B* A<T>::foo() {...}`

same for this line : `return new B();` -> `return new typename A<T>::B();`

Read: [Where and why do I have to put the "template" and "typename" keywords?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords)